# One of my players "adopted" an orphan girl, how do I go about this?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, followers-and-hirelings

I DM a game for 4-6 people. I'm a newer DM but am quite comfortable doing it.

One of my players, a dwarven princess, has decided to adopt a young orphan girl who was begging on the streets as her squire. I ultimately let her do this as I think it can be fun in the game.

She has bought her some leather armor and a small dagger, she plans on training her in combat.

Obviously the little girl will never see actual combat (or at least, not be directly involved) and I already have plans for her to potentially leave later on. Right now, I'm just confused on how to go forward with this NPC.

Should I be creating a character sheet for her? Maybe add a -4 to every stat since she is just a child?

Any input would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Neat, and with that out of the way, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related: [How much time would it take for a PC to train NPCs to get class features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104486), [How long would it take to teach a 6 year old magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95490)

Comment: This question seems a bit too unclear right now to be meaningfully answerable. I'm sure there are aspects of this issue that can be answered well here, but as written, it seems a bit too open-ended, especially the end of the question that broadly asks for "any input". What particular aspects of the topic are you asking about? How to best "stat" an NPC? How to stat a child NPC, or whether to even do so? What aspect(s) of the issue are you confused/unsure about?

Comment: Or how to use the NPC in campaign?

Comment: Does the player want to bring the NPC into combat encounters?  Have you tried discussing with the player to explain your preferences about this?

Comment: If she's just a child (and then should be a page, not a squire), or a squire (and therefore at least 14)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest having a talk with your player about this. Involving a child in adventuring, let alone combat, is potentially very problematic and could be upsetting for the players at the table.

You and your player(s) need to come to an agreement: Is this NPC going to be involved in combat, which potentially involves serious injury or death, or is this NPC going to go "hide in a safe place" any time combat starts and is just kind of protected by the narrative from traps, flame jets, and other hazards of adventuring? If 'training the kid to fight' is just a bit of down-time stage business -- a little descriptive text that doesn't mean anything more than what it says -- but the kid stays safely out of dungeons and suchlike, then maybe it's not an issue at all.

If the player intends this child to be right there in the thick of combat, hoping to get some kind of advantage out of it, then you may need to clear that with the group as a whole and discuss what the NPC is even capable of.

If that's the direction you decide to go, and your group is okay with having children in mortal peril, then I would think a commoner with slightly reduced stats would probably be a good baseline for this. Do keep in mind that this character is unlikely to be proficient with any armor or weapons, which has implications on their ability to fight at all.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want this character to actually be represented in a fight (instead of being an RP hook that can be helpful with mundane things outside of combat, such as running errands for you) and assuming your players are okay with a child being in potential peril...

### Noncombatants

D&D 5E has a precedent for how it handles children: It labels them as "noncombatants" and doesn't bother giving them a statblock, much less a character sheet.

For instance, in *Tomb of Annihilation*, a 6-year-old named [Na](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/monsters-and-npcs#MwaxanarandNa) is described as follows (p. 228):

> The young Prince Na is a noncombatant with AC 10 and 3 hit points.

In [a sidebar elsewhere in the same adventure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/fane-of-the-night-serpent#PrisonersoftheYuanti), the description of a 10-year-old named Tahvo says (p. 118):

> Tahvo, a ten-year-old boy (LG male Chultan human noncombatant with AC 10 and 2 hit points), [...]

In *Forgotten Relics* (the sample adventure in the *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* book), the description of the character [Caden d'Orien](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/building-eberron-adventures-forgotten-relics#CadendOrien), mentioned as being a six-year-old later in the section, simply says (p. 265):

> Caden d’Orien (noncombatant) is [...]

Even in places where statblocks such as 'Commoner' are used to refer to NPCs, children often don't get a statblock at all--they may be listed with an AC and some HP, but they have no appreciable skills and no ability to meaningfully fight.

### Commoner

If you want the kid to have some ability to fight, then I'd recommend the Commoner stat-block as a starting point, perhaps with reduced attributes to represent their age. This is a normal, mundane child – handing them a knife and teaching them how to use it doesn't make them a competent, trained combatant.

### Character Sheet?

PCs are remarkable individuals... Most people don't level up like they do; most people aren't *capable* of the heights of skill a PC can reach, much less the speed with which they can reach those heights. Most NPCs are represented with a simple statblock that (where it is similar) is inferior in many ways to a PC--even an NPC Archmage has fewer total features than a player's wizard class.

I would not expect a random orphan picked up off the streets to have the talent to assume a PC class. Giving the kid an actual character sheet with a PC class would basically mean your player tripped over an orphan prodigy.

I've handled situations like this in the past, and I've found that it works best to either label NPC followers as noncombatants (and keep them out of fights – which helps prevent combat-bloat as well) or to give them a simple stat block.

Trying to give them an actual character sheet with actual class levels is a lot of bookkeeping, complicates gameplay, and tends to make random NPC minions more powerful than they ought to be. Instead, if an NPC grows enough in skill, I may increase their HP, or bump them up to a 'stronger' statblock – such as Commoner > Bandit/Guard > Lord's Alliance Guard > Soldier/Thug, tweaked for consistency.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are already planning for this character to not be in combat and just be an NPC for role play. So you probably don’t need a character sheet since this is your decision.

However, I do have a couple of experiences that might be relevant to your game.

I played a short D&D 3e campaign where all the characters were children. BBEG was a level 1 wizard. All of us players had lower stats, one or two simple class features, and limited equipment. It made for a very different D&D experience, but very fun. You might be able to find an opportunity for a special session with your group doing something like this with your player’s orphan.

I also played a campaign where the GM played each session as a different generation of a family over a long period of time. We had rules for how our characters one session would pass on traits to their children to be characters for the next session. You could potentially look forward to the orphan growing up between adventures in your campaign. “It’s been 15 years since your triumph over evil. A great time of peace in the land. But now you must join together again...”

Answer (score 2):

Communication is key here. Find out if the player wants to teach the child enough for self-defense, or if they're wanting to train a child-soldier. Is the child meek and timid, or a hardened street urchin? You can use random generated personality traits, if you don't wish to impart bias. Play to the child's mentality, and how aware (if at all) she is to the cruelties of the world. If training and having her see combat traumatizes or mentally damages her, she could grow up to resent the player and return later as an advisary.
As with mounts, being trained not to flee from danger enables aggression.

(For published content...)
As general rule, it's not a good idea to give a **full** stat block to nonessential/ individual NPC's that you don't want murdered. A list of skills and bonuses is fine, but once you assign hit points, you're greatly increasing the potential for it to be killed. Especially don't let your players know it's stats, as someone will likely try to circumvent or exploit this info

Answer (score 2):

#### The Basics

Adding a new NPC to the game, especially if they will usually be around the party, should matter in some way. I tend to think of this sort of plot development as bringing new opportunities to the party while also introducing new challenges. These are factors which the game world imposes, so you as DM have to drive **and balance** them.

At a minimum, the dwarven princess has taken on a new set of responsibilities. If your table uses lifestyle maintenance costs, a good representation of that would be requiring the princess to pay to support another person. If the party now needs to provide for her safety, you can insist that they explain how they do that. Will they leave her in their stronghold, and if so, who looks after her? If they take her adventuring, how will they keep her away from monsters?

These sorts of questions should be presented to the players directly: make clear what the stakes are, that you expect the players to take them seriously, and that doing nothing is not an option. The game abstracts away a lot of "realistic" elements, so it's important to make clear that this is something the party needs to explicitly deal with. The party failing to live up to their newfound responsibilities doesn't necessarily mean the orphan will die-- she can run away, be adopted by someone more stable, or any number of other options.

Opportunities are a bit more open-ended. It's probably not ideal to add the child as a general adventuring companion, complete with useful Attributes and Skills; that exposes the child to the dangers of adventuring and suggests that they are a full party member, just as the PCs are. That's hard to mesh with a child character. But keeping the child safe and well-tended might grant the dwarven princess inspiration, for a mechanical benefit, and/or plot advantages for non-mechanical benefits.

**In summary, the ward should require investing in-game resources and possibly table time to maintain, but be worth that expenditure in some way. But both should be present: the opportunity, and the burden.**

#### What do you want the child to bring to your campaign?

All game elements that are not the PCs are under your control as DM, and they should be used thoughtfully to express details about the campaign setting and/or plot. With that in mind, what is the former urchin's role in your game? Is she an important piece of the dwarven princess' character story? Is she primarily going to symbolize some theme of your campaign plot or setting? Do/will significant plot events hinge on her in some way?

The dwarven princess may or may not have plans for their new ward. But you, as DM, *absolutely should* have plans for her. It's not my place to tell you exactly what those plans should be, but a player identifying and pursuing plot elements in the game is a great opportunity. They've indicated a plot hook that interests them. Use it!

I, personally, suggest using the child primarily as a plot device. Adventuring is dangerous, violence involving child characters isn't fun for many players and is easy to do a poor job with, and it's hard to justify a street urchin child as having many (or any) adventurer-relevant skills. That means that giving the child a full character sheet is probably overdetermined-- they shouldn't be dealing with the same obstacles as the adventurers, and certainly not in the same ways.

In any case, **this NPC is a lever you can use to advance stories.** Villains can try to get to the princess by posing some threat to the child; the child can get into mischief on her own, forcing the party to clean up after her; she can provide an innocent (or cynical) perspective on plot events; she can make requests of the party, or have a heartfelt desire that the party can satisfy for her. Planning what role you want the orphan to have in the story, and then developing her enough to accomplish that, will help keep you focused on the relevant aspects of her presence in the game. Thinking of her as a non-player story element, rather than a non-player *character*, might be helpful.

Comment: Plus she is an orphan who knows who her real parents were, displaced aristocracy killed by assassins, demon worshipers who promised her to their demon leader, polymorphed dragons, exiled royalty killed by her dead "parents", oh the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I have had almost the exact same thing happen in a game I played. As a party we decided to adopt a pair of twins we had saved, the DM was at first thrown by this, he expected us to just dump them off on another NPC.

What followed was a very real discussion about how this would play out. It was agreed very quickly that logistically taking 2 9yo children adventuring was not realistic. So the party found someone to take care of them when we where not in our home town. This actually ended up taking about 9 hours of game time as we vetted, searched and found suitable guardians. We where given plenty of opportunities to return and actually at one point when it looked like we would spend an extended amount of time in another continent we considered relocating them. In the end our DM allowed us to “find” a communication device, 2 glass orbs that allowed direct real time communication across the planes with no range limit. As a party we paid keep and expenses and also hired tutors and clerks to train the children while we where away. We allowed them to decide what they wanted to do and be, when the campaign ended both knew 3 languages and had started on the path one to be a fighter the other a cleric.

I think you need to have a realistic talk with your player and explain the reality, you also need to make sure that she is prepared for the NPC to die very quickly the first combat. Maybe build in a plan for her to find a perfect permenamt home, or suggest the players take the same approach deciding on a monthly cost for upkeep and looking after. If the player does insist on going adventuring with the child then you need to make a choice are you going to go easy, in which case the party have a familiar that you will never kill and they can just send places to scout or try and steal stuff, or do you try and teach a lesson that adventuring is hard.